# How to set high quality audio and microphone using bluetooth headset?

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, microphone, headset

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and I use an headset as input and output, but currently I only can use the microphone with low quality audio.

I can use the A2DP for high quality but when I select headset microphone, the system automatically changes the output to HFP (handsfree).
I already tried some solutions like:

- install pavucontrol
- install bluez/blueman
- adjust the `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` file for multiple profiles and `Disable=headset`
- remove and pair headset again (after tried all of these steps)

Is there a way to enable high quality output and maintain the headset microphone?

I searched before ask here and I saw some persons talking about this being not possible currently due to pulseaudio limitations, but I also found a forum post (which I'm still searching again to post here) with some users solving in their OS. So, I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

Comment: Do you find a solution? Same issue here

Comment: @NicolasSmith I didn't. I use a [gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/) to select input/output, to be more practical. Then, I change to headset mic when I enter in a call and switch back to the A2DP when the call is over.